# Dynamic Edit Form in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-editform

I'm trying to create a reusable form using Blazor InputBase and EditForm components.
(I omitted most of the code related to model binding, but the idea is that the component receive a model, and determine the fields from the properties and generate the input fields)

So far I have the following component

```
<EditForm Model="@Model" 
              OnInvalidSubmit="OnInvalidSubmit" 
              OnValidSubmit="OnInvalidSubmit">
        @CustomRender
    </EditForm>

@code {
[Parameter] public TModel Model { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnInvalidSubmit { get; set; }

public RenderFragment CustomRender { get; set; }

public RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder =>
{
    base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    builder.OpenElement(0, "nav");
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "menu");
    builder.AddAttribute(2, "value", "Hello");
    builder.CloseElement();
    builder.OpenComponent(3, typeof(InputText)); // here's the problem
    // builder.AddAttribute(4, "@bind-Value", "myValue");
    builder.CloseComponent();
};    

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    RenderComponent();
}

protected void RenderComponent()
{
    CustomRender = CreateComponent();
}
```

Let me explain a bit the idea, I'm supposed to call this component from anywhere else (*as a nuget package for example*) like this

```
<Tabla Model="@MyModel"></Tabla>
```

My question is, should I use the structure I described here *(EditForm, InputBase,etc)* or should I use **plain HTML** elements such as **Form**, **input type="text"** **"number"** and create them manually?

Check the following line

```
 builder.OpenComponent(3, typeof(InputText))
```

This line is supposed to open a Blazor InputText *(I think)*, but due to missing attributes like "bind-Value" this is not working.
Again don't worry about the model binding (I've already obtained the props via reflection), my issue is with the instantiation of these components that inherit from InputBase).

Comment: "my issue is with ..." ok, but _what_ is your issue?  I don't see a clear problem statement.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for https://www.meziantou.net/automatically-generate-a-form-from-an-object-in-blazor.htm